# FileStream constructor with FileOptions argument. Is this still valid .NET 5?

Tags: filestream, .net-5

According to the [.NET 5 documentation for the FileStream class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-5.0), it still takes a constructor that permits the user to pass in a FileOptions argument.

```
FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare, Int32, FileOptions)
```

Yet in practice, the constructor does not seem to be there.  Even when I navigate to decompiled sources, I don't see it there Does anyone know if this is a documentation oversight or am I missing something?

Note that I am building my .NET 5 application with a windows target, if that matters

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Also, if it matters, this is what I'm trying to do (which does not build)

```
string path = Path.Combine(Folder, "temp-lock-delete-me.tmp");
_preventRenameFs = new FileStream(
    path, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite,
    FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Write | FileShare.Read,
    4096,
    FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

Comment: Where's the `FileMode` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code you need to add `FileMode` argument

```
string path = Path.Combine(Folder, "temp-lock-delete-me.tmp");
_preventRenameFs = new FileStream(
    path, 
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate,// <-- add FileMode
    FileAccess.ReadWrite,
    FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Write | FileShare.Read,
    4096,
    FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

Comment: I must have stared at that for 35 minutes yet  never once saw what was right in front me.  I feel like an idiot.  Thank you.